# building multiple pivot tables from one data source

Tags: c#, excel, ssis-2012

I'm trying to create multiple pivot tables
from one data source but keep
getting reuse from the first pivot table -
this is my code -

```
int lastRow = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row;
pivotTableName = @"PivotPableNameA";
pivotData[0] = ws.Range["A1:B"+lastRow];
pivotDestination[0] = wsP.Range["A1", useDefault];

wb.PivotTableWizard(
        XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase,
        pivotData[0],
        pivotDestination[0],
        pivotTableName,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        useDefault,
        useDefault,
        false,
        false,
        XlOrder.xlDownThenOver,
        1,
        useDefault,
        useDefault
);

// Set variables used to manipulate the Pivot Table.
pivotTable[0] = (PivotTable)wsP.PivotTables(pivotTableName);

itemcodePivotField[0] = (PivotField)pivotTable[0].PivotFields(2);
descriptionPivotField[0] = (PivotField)pivotTable[0].PivotFields(1);
countPivotField[0] = (PivotField)pivotTable[0].PivotFields(2);

// Format the Pivot Table.
pivotTable[0].Format(XlPivotFormatType.xlReport2);
pivotTable[0].InGridDropZones = false;
pivotTable[0].SmallGrid = false;
pivotTable[0].ShowTableStyleRowStripes = true;
pivotTable[0].TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleLight1";

// Row Fields
itemcodePivotField[0].Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
itemcodePivotField[0].Position = 1;

// Colum Fields
descriptionPivotField[0].Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
descriptionPivotField[0].Position = 1;

// Data Field
countPivotField[0].Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
countPivotField[0].Function = XlConsolidationFunction.xlCount;
```

I tried taking twice the data source but it keeps re-using
the first table and just moving it to another cell
Y.D

Comment: trying to add this second part of the code -

Comment: pivotTableName = "PivotPableNameB";
    pivotData[1] = ws.Range["A1:B" + lastRow];
    pivotDestination[1] = wsP.Range["F1", useDefault];
    
    wb.PivotTableWizard(
            XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase,
            pivotData[1],
            pivotDestination[1],
            pivotTableName,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            useDefault,
            useDefault,
            false,
            false,
            XlOrder.xlDownThenOver,
            1,
            useDefault,
            useDefault
    );

Comment: // Set variables used to manipulate the Pivot Table.
    pivotTable[1] = (PivotTable)wsP.PivotTables(pivotTableName);
    
    itemcodePivotField[1] = (PivotField)pivotTable[1].PivotFields(2);
    descriptionPivotField[1] = (PivotField)pivotTable[1].PivotFields(1);
    countPivotField[1] = (PivotField)pivotTable[1].PivotFields(2);

Comment: // Format the Pivot Table.
    pivotTable[1].Format(XlPivotFormatType.xlReport2);
    pivotTable[1].InGridDropZones = false;
    pivotTable[1].SmallGrid = false;
    pivotTable[1].ShowTableStyleRowStripes = true;
    pivotTable[1].TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleLight1";
    
    // Row Fields
    //descriptionPivotField.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
    //descriptionPivotField.Position = 1;
    itemcodePivotField[1].Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
    itemcodePivotField[1].Position = 1;

Comment: // Data Field
    countPivotField[1].Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
    countPivotField[1].Function = XlConsolidationFunction.xlCount;

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
you should use PivotCache - to make it clear lets make an array of pivotcache and pivot table -
for first table in the spreadsheet we would use PivotCache[0] and PivotTable[0] and for second pivot table we should use PivotCache[1] and PivotTable[1] as shown in the example -

```
        pivotCache[0] = (Excel.PivotCache)wb.PivotCaches().Add(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, pivotData[0]);
        pivotTable[0] = (Excel.PivotTable)wsP.PivotTables().Add(PivotCache: pivotCache[0], TableDestination: pivotDestination[0], TableName: pivotTableName);


        pivotCache[1] = (Excel.PivotCache)wb.PivotCaches().Add(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, pivotData[1]);
        pivotTable[1] = (Excel.PivotTable)wsP.PivotTables().Add(PivotCache: pivotCache[1], TableDestination: pivotDestination[1], TableName: pivotTableName);
```

this part shouldn't be used for my point of view

```
wb.PivotTableWizard(....)
// Set variables used to manipulate the Pivot Table.
pivotTable[0] = (PivotTable)wsP.PivotTables(pivotTableName);

wb.PivotTableWizard(....)
// Set variables used to manipulate the Pivot Table.
pivotTable[1] = (PivotTable)wsP.PivotTables(pivotTableName);
```

Comment: Yes, i found work around via the pvotcache, thanks